# Converting user input and converting it to a word docx with styles uisng php and html

Tags: php, html

I have this code that will convert the user input into a word docx. I'm trying to put styles(size, font, etc) upon the code but I can't figure it out. this is the code for far

I'm trying to put styles(size, font, etc) upon the code but I can't figure it out. this is the code for far

```
   <?php
    if (isset($_POST['convert']))
    {
        header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");  
           header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=".rand().".doc");  
           header("Pragma: no-cache");  
           header("Expires: 0");  
           echo '<h1>'.$_POST["heading"].'</h1>';  
           echo $_POST["description"];  
    } 
   ?>
```

Comment: What have you actually researched or tried? There is no genuine attempt here. Docx is a complex format...find a php library (by googling it!) which can help you generate docx files, and use that. Stackoverflow can help you where necessary but it's not a replacement for doing some basic research. See also [ask] and the [tour] please.

Comment: Try [PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you are using the correct syntax,
Here is my example:

```
<?php
$_POST['convert'] = 'tested 0000' ; 
$_POST["heading"] = 'heading'; 
$_POST["description"] = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. " ;  


if (isset($_POST['convert']))
{
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");  
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;Filename=".rand().".doc");  
    header("Pragma: no-cache");  
    header("Expires: 0");  

    echo '<html>
    <head>
    <style>
    .heading {
        font-size: 60px;
        font-weight: bold;
        color:red;
    }
    .description {
        font-size: 14px;
        background:pink;
        font-style : italic;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>';


    echo '<h1 class="heading">'.$_POST["heading"].'</h1>';  
    echo '<p class="description" >'.$_POST["description"].'</p>';  

    echo '</body>
    </html>';
```

If you want to use a library that manage that: https://phpword.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: This produces HTML, not docx or doc. Word can open such a file, potentially, but it doesn't mean it's actually in the specified file format.

Comment: It works and generates a Doc file, here is the proof: https://imgur.com/a/Gr7nnkP

Comment: No, it generates a HTML file with a .doc extension. That is not the same as a file in actual doc format, or in [docx format](https://docs.fileformat.com/word-processing/docx/) (which is specfically what the OP asked for). Setting a file extension does not magically transform the file format. Like I said already, Word can open such a HTML file, but it doesn't contain data conforming to the [docx specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-docx/728a7abc-7f55-40dc-90a7-1276ff53c8b2). You would not be able to use all features of Word with such a file.

Comment: You could also open that file in Notepad and see the raw HTML. If you do that with a real doc or docx file, you would see a lot of binary data.